# TYPO3 HTML5 closing tags

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript, fluid

I have set the following in the typoscript:

```
config.doctype = html5
```

nevertheless I get the following output:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="generator" content="TYPO3 CMS" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
<meta name="author" content="test" />
<meta name="keywords" content="TYPO3" />
<meta name="description" content="Bootstrap" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
```

I want to remove the slashes at the end. How can I do that?

I also get the slash on some content items

```
<img class="image-embed-item" title="title" alt="alt" width="50" height="50" loading="lazy" />
```

that should also be removed. What is the best way to proceed?

Comment: "I want to remove the slashes at the end." — this seems like a complete waste of your time. HTML allows them. Modern browsers don't have bugs relating to them. They can have issues when interacting with unquoted attribute values, but you don't have any of those.

Comment: I have to do this because I get complained about when an agency tests them.

Comment: Sounds like the agency doesn't know what they are doing and someone is wasting a lot of money on them.

Comment: You would kind of hope that the typo3 people would take a passing glance at the HTML standard at least when they created their thing.

Comment: It's interesting that an advertising agency is the one that wants to follow the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also think, that this is waste of time. But if you really need to do this you could add the meta-data via TypoScript headerdata:

```
page.headerData {
10 = TEXT
10.value (
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="generator" content="TYPO3 CMS">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
    <meta name="author" content="test">
    <meta name="keywords" content="TYPO3">
    <meta name="description" content="Bootstrap">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
)
```

}

Check in the TypoScript-Object-Browser if 10 is occupied before. In case it is use a free number. (i.e. 20 ;-)

To remove the slash in the image tag, i think the only way is to implement your own viewhelper. Maybe you could xclass the tag-based-viewhelper to achive  non-closing tags for all tag-based viewhelper.

**EDIT:**

If all that doesn't fit your requirements, the only way i see is to implement a middleware to remove all the closing tags.

First implement the configuration in your extension.

/Configuration/RequestMiddlewares.php

```
<?php

return [
    'frontend' => [
        'remove-closing-tags-middleware' => [
            'target' => \VENDOR\ExtName\Middleware\RemoveClosingTagsMiddleware::class,
            'after' => [
                // Check Configuration for middlewares in Backend and replace last-middleware
                // as described here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/RequestHandling/Index.html#debugging
                'last-middleware',
            ]
        ],
    ]
];
```

And then implement the middleware in your extension.

/Classes/Middleware/RemoveClosingTagsMiddleware.php

```
<?php
namespace VENDOR\ExtName\Middleware;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\MiddlewareInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\NullResponse;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\Stream;

class RemoveClosingTagsMiddleware implements MiddlewareInterface
{


    public function process(ServerRequestInterface $request, RequestHandlerInterface $handler): ResponseInterface
    {
        $response = $handler->handle($request);
        if ($response instanceof NullResponse) {
            return $response;
        }
        $body = $response->getBody();
        $body->rewind();
        $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        $content = str_replace('/>', '>', $content);
        $body = new Stream('php://temp', 'rw');
        $body->write($content);
        return $response->withBody($body);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to adjust VENDOR and ExtName to your extension.

Further information can be found here:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/RequestHandling/Index.html

and here:

https://reelworx.at/blog/detail/correct-manipulation-of-generated-html-in-typo3/

Comment: That's not going to remove the ones from void elements in the body (which the question explicitly mentioned).

Comment: TYPO3 is generating this two:

<meta name="generator" content="TYPO3 CMS" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />

Comment: Updated my answer with a middleware solution.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought of a middleware yet. That worked. I only added that ' />' is also replaced.