encode output of TYPO3 12 Site to iso-88591 with middleware
in TYPO3 12 config.metaCharset is removed so there is no easy possibility anymore to encode the output of a TYPO3 site to iso-8859-1. Breaking #97065 tells me that i should use a custom middleware to encode the output on my own. I am familiar with middleware in in other topics, but i don`t know how to solve exactly this problem.
With return new HtmlResponse($content); it should be possible to return the encoded content to the world, but how do i get the whole content of an aktual page in a middleware?
Or is there a other possibility?
Any help appreciated!

In this question i helped someone to remove closing tags with a middleware: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76555573/typo3-html5-closing-tags/76555832#76555832
Maybe this helps you  by your Question.

Mogens response it a good example; remember to also use withHeader to specify the proper HTTP Content-Type headers that you set to ISO. However, may I ask: Have you considered switching to UTF-8? This would be a more futureproof migration. UTF-8 will give you these sweet emoji, too.... ;)

While an individual middleware for ISO-8859-1 only might be a relatively easy approach , It's the question if this is a good approach in the longer run. Considering that languages that need other ISO encodings might be added, perhaps it's better to create an extension that is capable to handle several languages and is choosing the according ISO charset then as output.

Another independent thought is, if it's good just to convert the whole output, or if the html or json should be left untouched and the conversion process only done for the content, the result might be the same but restricting it to the content avoids that potentially problematic parts like i.e. inline-scripts will be parsed (if they are added on page level).

Still another thought: perhaps create the ISO output only for a special page type, while keeping the UTF-8 output as option, depending on the URL parameters.

btw: a quick and perhaps dirty approach for everything would be to use stdWrap with a postUserFunc on the page itself. This would process the whole page though and might ignore to set the correct headers perhaps, like @GarvinHicking advised.

i would ask the general question why do you need ISO-8859-1 as UTF-8 covers a far greater character range. without beeing much bigger. (for iso 8859-1 characters)

I need the iso encoding only for a group of pages which are used as html templates for a newsletter. The newsletter system of my client can only manage iso encoded html. Why? I dont know :-) Perhaps because an old IBM mainframe is in use there.

With the help of some comments (thanks a lot!!) i was able to build my middleware:
public function process(ServerRequestInterface $request, RequestHandlerInterface $handler): ResponseInterface
{
    $response = $handler->handle($request);
    $response = $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');

    ob_start([__CLASS__, 'callback']);
    return $response;
}

/**
 * @param $buffer
 * @return array|string|string[]
 */
private function callback($buffer) {
    // evtl. weitere Konvertierungen
    $buffer = mb_convert_encoding($buffer, "iso-8859-1", "utf-8");
    $buffer = str_replace('charset=utf-8', 'charset=iso-8859-1',$buffer);
    return $buffer;
}

the magic tool here is starting a stream with ob_start. I found this in an other middleware of the core (compressing the content of the page).
